# Can you retrieve all envelope properties in one API call?

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I'm using the C# DocuSign API to retrieve information regarding an envelope:

```
Configuration apiConfiguration = GetApiConfiguration();
EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiConfiguration);
var envelope = envelopesApi.GetEnvelope(AccountId, envelopeId);
```

I need certain fields from `var envelope` such as: `InitialSendDate`, which is available. I also know I am going to need the data available in `CustomFields` and `Recipients`. These two properties are returned as null from the `GetEnvelope` request. Is there any way to specify additional properties (or better yet, all of the properties) that you want populated from the `GetEnvelope` call? Or is there another, more appropriate API method that returns a summation of the envelope?

Currently, I'm making additional API calls to retrieve the data:

```
CustomFieldsEnvelope customFields = envelopesApi.ListCustomFields(AccountId, envelopeId);
Recipients recipients = envelopesApi.ListRecipients(AccountId, envelopeId);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `custom_fields`, `recipients` and `tabs` in a single call by calling below endpoint

```
GET /restapi/v2/accounts/<accountId>/envelopes/<envelopeId>?include=custom_fields,recipients,tabs&advanced_update=true
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a single API call that will retrieve all the information you're looking for. By design, the [Get Envelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/get/) operation only returns top-level property values, along with URIs that can be used to subsequently be used to retrieve other data such as recipients, custom fields, documents, etc.

If you're concerned about API throttling limits, and/or want to limit the number of API requests you need to make to retrieve the information you've described, you might consider configuring [DocuSign Connect](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide-connect) for your account (or individually for each Envelope via the **Create Envelope** API request) to send HTTP notifications to your app when Envelope events occur (e.g., Envelope Completed, etc.). The payload of a Connect notification will contain all data for the envelope (provided that you've configured it that way), and because it's a webhook, you don't have to make any API requests to retrieve that Envelope information.